# problem with inserted newlines in downloaded files and displayed images from cakephp/apache/linux

Tags: php, image, cakephp, download

I've got a cakephp application that works on many other machines, but when I installed it on one particular Ubuntu/Apache2/PHP 5.3.3 machine, every file I download has an extra newline inserted at the beginning of the file.

My images won't display on my browser from this server, and when I right-click>>>save image as, the image will be saved with an extra newline at the start.  This saved image is not displayable on my local machine, but as soon as I remove that extra newline, the image displays fine.

The same thing happens for text files downloaded from this application (the application allows users to upload and download files, such as these text files and images).  All stored images on the server are correct, I can copy them over to my local machine and they display correctly, so the newline is somehow added from my application in rendering.

I made a simple test script (stolen from php.net) that works on this same server as a stand-alone php script:

```
<?php
ob_clean();
header("Content-type: image/gif");
$im = imagecreate (100, 50);
imagegif($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

When I use this script included inside my application at the point where I would normally display images, I get the same behavior: that is the image isn't displayed, but when I right-click>>>save image as, I can download the image, remove the newline, and correctly display the black box gif generated.

I even thought the ob_clean() call would remove any previous data in the buffers, but it did not (or I should say it didn't fix my problem).

Any ideas on how to debug this?

Comment: You could make a comparison test with installing and using php-cgi. Rename your script into .cgi and add the shebang, and look if the issue persists. Also try with the commandline version. -- Might be a php.ini issue (eg auto_prepend_file).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a comparison on `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` among the various servers? You may be running different versions / extensions? Maybe there is something different between them that inserts a NULL when it should be running a function or something.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.

It turned out that there was an extra newline at the end of a php config file for a custom application in cake, that was "include"-ed.  The newline occurred after the closing "?>" in the script, and was emitted as output.

```
ob_clean();
```

Didn't remove the newline for some reason.  Before I had figured out exactly where this occurred, I had found a higher level include that was calling into the code that caused the newline to be printed.  When I surrounded this include like so:

```
ob_start();
include(whatever);
ob_end_clean();
```

it did prevent the newline from displaying.  Only later on I found the exact place where the newline was.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 7 years old now, but I'd like to share an easy way to find the problematic file (under unix), assuming the problem is caused by a newline after a `?>` closed php tag:

```
pcregrep -r -M --include='\.php$' '\?>\n' root/of/the/project
```

`pcregrep` is a `grep` varian that allows for multiline matching, so with that command I'm listing all .php files with a newline after the closing tag.